# How Can I extract order details for every first customer order with mysql

Tags: mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm tying to extract from my Prestashop 1.6 the following info for every first customer  order:

```
ID customer
sex
age
order date
total amount spent
product category
Newsletter subscription yes or not
using VAT yes or not
Using coupon yes or not
payment method
device or OS (it is the device the customer was connected from)
```

Is here anyone who can help me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: "first" customer with regard to _which_ other column(s) ?

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) to provide a user case with example data and expected results, without that we cant help you and this question is simply unclear..